# How to generate API key from .net core mvc service? (with Authentication in middleware)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a .NET core MVC rest service that restricts access to the API by validating a key.

It uses a middleware function that inspects the request for a valid key (before routing to the api function) and returns an unauthorized response if it is not valid.

**My problem is how can I generate the key?** Since all requests go through this middleware that checks if the key is valid, I need a way to generate the key.

I know it is common to have a separate identity server but I believe it is overkill for my situation, where a valid key gives access to the entire API. There is no permissions structure.

I could examine the incoming request for some indication that the user is trying to authenticate with a username+password and return the key, but this does not seem correct.

**Is there a way I can allow a single service call to skip the middleware?**

The middleware function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace PatrolLiveRestService.Middleware
{
    public class KeyValidatorMiddleware
    {

        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        //private IContactsRepository ContactsRepo { get; set; }

        public KeyValidatorMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)//, IContactsRepository _repo)
        {
            _next = next;
            //ContactsRepo = _repo;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("api-key"))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 400; //Bad Request                
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("API Key is missing");
                return;
            }
            if (!context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("device-id"))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 400; //Bad Request                
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Device ID is missing");
                return;
            }

            string apiKey = context.Request.Headers["api-key"];
            int deviceId;
            if (!int.TryParse(context.Request.Headers["device-id"], out deviceId))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //UnAuthorized
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid Device ID");
                return;
            }

            if (!Common.ServiceCommon.IsKeyValid(apiKey, deviceId))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //UnAuthorized
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid API Key");
                return;
            }

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }


    }

    #region ExtensionMethod
    public static class UserKeyValidatorsExtension
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder ApplyUserKeyValidation(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<KeyValidatorMiddleware>();
            return app;
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Adding the middleware in Startup.cs Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
...
    app.ApplyUserKeyValidation();
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see three ways around:

- check context.Request.Url inside your `KeyValidatorMiddleware` (e.g. for path `/no-need-for-api-key-endpoint` don't force api-key header presence
- alter your `KeyValidatorMiddleware` - instead of rejecting requests without api-key header, just set the `context.User` property to a `ClaimsPrincipal` with claims being device id and api key for valid incoming requests and filter out requests without valid authorization on controller level via `[Authorize]` attribute
- do not implement it as middleware, implement it as action filter instead

Comment: functions with `[Authorize]` attribute will only be called if `context.User` exists?

Comment: @JamesWierzba - more or less; practically it is like context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true ...

Comment: Ok I'm leaning towards option 3 (action filter). I tried option 2 and it seems like I have no control over what happens when a service function gets called and there is no authorized user ( it returns generic 500 error whereas I wish to return specific code and message)

Comment: I have implemented an action filter but I do not know how to short circuit the pipeline when the authentication fails. do you know how I can return the response from the filter? I can't find any documentation